# TSQL to get the schema to which a FileTable belongs

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to list and delete all `FileTables` in my database via a script.

Selecting from `sys.filetables` does not return the schema to which the `FileTable` belongs, while selecting from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` does not indicate whether the table is a `filetable` or not.

I'd rather not do a join between the two to find common names as this is not a general solution in the event that a `FileTable` and regular table have the same name.

Does anyone know of a query to list all `FileTables` along with the `schema` to which they belong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.filetables` exposes `object_id`. That should be enough to find the object name and schema using the built-ins [`OBJECT_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx) and [`OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx):

```
SELECT
  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) as schema_name,
  OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as table_name,
  *
  FROM sys.filetables;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**`SYS.TABLES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187406.aspx)

```
+--------------+-----------+-------------------------+
|Column name   |Data type  |Description              |
+--------------+-----------+-------------------------+
|is_filetable  |bit        |1 = Table is a FileTable |
+--------------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT Schema_Name = s.NAME, 
       Filetable_Name = t.NAME 
FROM   sys.tables t 
       JOIN sys.schemas s 
         ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
WHERE  t.is_filetable = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but I have gone with Remus' answer as it doesn't require a join